# alternative to remove size attribute for responsive page

Tags: javascript, css

I want `textfield` of size say "X"px. Now to make the page responsive I removed the `size` attribute. But this change has reduced the actual size of `textfield`. Is there a way around to increase the size of the input box (not using `size` attribute)and also make it responsive? I used bootstrap `col-xs-2` etc but that is not helping my customized layout. Also note that this is not the first time I am stuck with such an issue. It happens with a requirement where special arrangement of divs and buttons happen in a row and to make it look consistent in all viewports. Please share your thought if anyone has faced similar issue and fixed the same.

**Edit**
I want to make the gap consistent across all resolutions.

```
    [div]gap[textfield]gap[div]
```

With size attribute value as 23

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="linstyle1">
      <label>text1</label>
   </div>

   <div id="some-textfield" class="left leftmargin">
     <!--struts tag populates a input field-->  
        <s:textfield name="input1" value="%{input}" size="23" maxlength="23" cssClass="form-control enter" required="required" />
   </div>

   <div id="desktop" class="left leftmargin">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-table-responsive " type="submit" name="button1" title="button1">
        </button>   
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you can use form-group and form-control class with text fields. These are responsive class

Comment: can you post the code for your div elements. Its hard to tell why that is not consistent if you are using it inside a form-control. may be a paddng-top and padding-bottom to textField can help you achieve your goal

Comment: I don't see any problem in gaps. I ran i in fiddle in two different resolution monitors.gaps are consistent

Comment: you are right but when I use an emulator (mobile iphon6 iphone6 plus nexus) on chrome and firefox I see in consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```css
.dPad {
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  width:10%;background:#0f0
}
.inFlex {
  position:absolute;
  width:60%;
  left:20%;
  right:20%
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="dPad" style="left:0px">left</div>
  <input type="text" class="inFlex" />
  <div class="dPad" style="right:0px">right</div>
</div>
```

Only issue is (without the gap, or depending on the size of the gap) you can not have a space between the `<div>` and the `<input>`. If you do, the layout might break.

Here is another option without a gap but note that the lack of white space between tags. That is important.

Also the default border and padding on the `<input>` is removed as that must be controlled in order to reach 100% (you can not trust what browsers do with input borders and padding).

```css
.dPad {
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  width:15%;background:#0f0
}
.inFlex {
  position:absolute;
  width:69%;
  left:15%;
  right:15%;
  border:0px;
  padding:0.5em 0.5%;
  background:#ff0
}
```

```html
<div><div 
  class="dPad" style="left:0px">left</div><input 
  type="text" class="inFlex" value="text field" /><div 
  class="dPad" style="right:0px">right</div></div>
```

In order to have a fixed width gap, you can do that as well by changing the percentage values to a `px` value then use the `@media` CSS switch (something like `@media all and (max-width:480px)` to adjust the `px` values at different screen size.

Comment: Thats exactly want I want to address isn't there a workaround for the same? Also, I wan to reduce the gap to 10px both just before and after the inputfield and want it consistent across all view (if this is done that would be also fine)

Comment: If you use percentages and have *no white space between tags*, so long as the width values add up to 100%, there is no issue. If you do have white space between tags however, you have to have  less than 100% on the width values - and the layout might break on small screens.

Comment: (context: small gap between divs and input) The problem with % according to me that it does not remain same across browsers for instance, IE's 5% percent is not same as Chrome or Firefox so coming back to consistency in gap. I find specifying 10px value in between gaps as more consistent. (small breathing space) But it wont work when the lot of tag are squeezed in a single row (not able to make the row size 100% ).

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the input field to 100% inside the bootstrap div, whichever it is. Setting the width to % based will make it responsive to adapt to all viewports.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>text1</label>
    </div>

    <div id="some-textfield" class="col-sm-6">
        <!--struts tag populates a input field-->   
        <s:textfield name="input1" value="%{input}" maxlength="23" cssClass="form-control enter" required="required" />
    </div>

    <div id="desktop" class="col-sm-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-table-responsive " type="submit" name="button1" title="button1"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap will take care of the gutter width by default. You don't have to add extra classes to set the width of divs.

Comment: Bootstrap width are in percents and is see gap not aligned accordingly

Comment: Check whether any css class or id is overriding the default margin and padding values of bootstrap divs using the browser inspector.

Answer (score 0):

you can use media query in CSS

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: can you provide plunkr link

Comment: wrap your textfield  in a div and then you can give the input size 100%. And then you can make the parent div responsive.

Comment: don't use size attribute in html tag. Instead use the css and give the width of input 100% which will be relative to your parent div, which already responsive. Isn't working?